RS232 isolated communication via MAX3250
I have a two diffrent boards. One of the board is send the SoC and other things to Charger Board. While charging progress starts I want to isolate this to device because battery ground is isolated to MCU ground. When I connect this board together I will connect MCU ground to Battery ground. Sender board is powered by this battery. While I am researching I see MAX3250, It is isolated RS232 Driver IC. At sender board I use MAX232, Can I do MAX232 -> MAX3250 combination? I don't want to change Sender board MAX232 to MAX3250 because MAX3250 is too expensive. How can I implement this to system. Basically 2 board has a MCU with diffrent grounds and between them there is a 2 RS232 IC to communicate.
MAX3250 datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX3250.pdf
Images reference is above datasheet.

Schematic of system:
(Additional components are didn't given (C1,C2,C3,C4 caps etc.))


Why would you use isolated RS232 over isolated RS422/RS485? Might as well send Maxim a blank check... "please bill me ridiculous amounts of money".

I didn't work with rs422/rs485 protocols before. I am building Charger board. Other board is already have a MAX232. Thats why I am looking for something to cooperate with Data Sender BOARD.

It's not a protocol, it's a hardware layer standard. Just like RS232 is not a protocol but a hardware layer standard - just an older and less rugged one. And it seems like 1000pcs of MAX3250 will cost you about as much as a decent car.

Thanks for reply. I find a ISO7721-Q1 dual chanel isolator from TI. MAX232 and ISO7721 total 2.9 USD. Not sure is it work or not I am looking for it. Much more good compared to price of car :)

Why do you really need isolation?  Are you sure, or does it just seem like "a good thing"?  What problem is isolation solving for you?

Its my duty actually Via rules of design. My charger input should be isolated to battery (battery=charger output). So as I mentioned if I use non isolated communication I would destroy isolation I get from charger(charger output and input isolated via transformer.

Actually If I was isolate charger input and mcu power I don't need that isolation
